# Problem in calling a variable from server to client

Tags: php, ajax

I want to learn ajax. 
Basically I begin to understand it, but I have one problem

here is my js code

```
$('#click').on('click',function () {
     var a="good";
     $.ajax({
       url:'/ggg.php',
       method:'post',
       data:{
           info:a
       },
       success:display_data
     })
});
```

here is my html code

```
<input type="submit" value="do it" id="click">
```

here is my php code

```
<?php
   echo $_POST['info'];
```

that's what I see in console.log
[image]

and the word "good" should appear

Comment: i think `success:display_data` should be `success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                },`

Comment: it did not help

Answer (score 3):

Use `type` instead of `method`. Also `success` might be a function.

```
$('#click').on('click',function () {
        var a="good";
        $.ajax({
            url:'/ggg.php',
            type: 'post',
            data:{
                info:a
            },
            success: function (data) {
                //document.write(data)
                console.log(data)
            }
        })
    });
```

[**Reference**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)